# How to get test name in Jest afterEach() hook

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

I'm using Jest and Typescript to test api. Currently I want to map the correlation Id to each test name. I have tried to print the test name in afterEAch() hook but it didn't work. It shows error syntax "Property 'getState' does not exist on type 'Expect'". Could someone help me out?
Please note I'm using Jest v27 and jest-circus as test runner

```
afterEach(() => {
  console.log(`Correlation ID: ${process.env.correlationId}`)
  console.log(expect.getState().currentTestName)
})
```

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7774

Comment: thanks @KarenGrigoryan, it worked! But I could not get the environment variable in handleTestEvent(), I have tried to console.log(process.env.correlationId), but it shows undefined. Could you please help one more time?

Comment: correlationid is not part of jest so I have no idea what that is